# MS-ACCESS Write Conflict Issue

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am having a write conflict issue. Not sure what the cause could be. The issue occurs when multiple users are using the Access database.

Below is a schematic of whats happening. The `(Main) Form` displays a `Subform` (with some data displayed from the `Table`). The user can double click a name to pull up that individuals details, via the `(Details) Form` that pops up. If changes are made, the user can save the details (actually, a prompt pops up asking if you would like to save when closing the window).
[image]

When saving, then going to open up another individuals details, the write conflict pops up.
[image]

The code when closing the `(Details) Form`:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

   ' This procedure checks to see if the data on the form has
   ' changed. If the data has changed, the procedure prompts the
   ' user to continue with the save operation or to cancel it. Then
   ' the action that triggered the BeforeUpdate event is completed.

   Dim ctl As Control

   On Error GoTo Err_BeforeUpdate

   ' The Dirty property is True if the record has been changed.
   If Me.Dirty Then
      ' Prompt to confirm the save operation.
      If MsgBox("Do you want to save?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
              "Save Record") = vbNo Then
         Me.Undo
      End If
   End If

Exit_BeforeUpdate:
   Exit Sub

Err_BeforeUpdate:
   MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
   Resume Exit_BeforeUpdate
End Sub
```

Which was taken from the Microsoft website (I think).

Is there something wrong with my data structure that is causing this?

If more information is needed, I can edit the post to include more code etc.

EDIT 1: Reversed `Subform` arrow. The `Subform` simply displays data from the `Table`.

EDIT 2: Backend is Access. To open the `(Details) Form` from the `Subform`:

```
Private Sub First_Name_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

DoCmd.OpenForm "Details", , , "[First Name] = '" & Me![First Name] & "' and [Last Name] = '" & Me![Last Name] & "'"

End Sub
```

EDIT 3:

While looking at the `(Main) Form`, the `Subform` has a Source Object set to the name of the `Subform`, which I call `QuerySF`. The `QuerySF` Form has a `Record Source` set to the `Table`. The pop-up `(Details) Form` has a Record Source set to the `Table`. I can instead set the Record Source for the `(Details) Form` to my Query, but I tried this and it did not help.

Would inserting a `Requery` somewhere help?

I have noticed the pop-up occurs every third time the `(Details) Form` is opened via the Subform.

Comment: Can users make changes to the data on the main subform?

Comment: Nope, it is locked so no changes can be made on the `Subform`. It is Enabled (so the user can double click to open `(Details) Form`), but locked so they cannot edit any fields.

Comment: Change `Me.Undo` to `Me.Cancel = True` and see if you still get the error. This should let you close the form without saving however if it doesn't put `Me.Dirty = False` after the `Me.Undo` instead

Comment: I can close the form fine without saving. The problem is when I do save. Also, `Me.Cancel` produced an error. And adding 'Me.Dirty = False` did not change anything.

Comment: What is your backend? Access, a server, or is it all in a single database? -- Usually this error pops up if you modify data via VBA and don't requery the form afterwards.

Comment: Also, what is the code for *then going to open up another individuals details* ?

Comment: I cannot replicate this issue. Disable the error handler and step debug. Perhaps need to post the Save button code. Why don't you use ID for criteria instead of names?

Comment: As June7 wrote, there is nothing here that would explain the behavior. My bet would still be on *some* code that runs during the process (e.g. when opening the Details form). Perhaps even a data macro or such.

Comment: Well, 90% of my Access GUI is written in VBA. I'll go through the code with a fine tooth comb to find the issue. Additionally, this ONLY happens when multiple people have the same Access database open.

Comment: ONLY when multiple people use - this is important info. Name of popup form is `Details`?

Comment: Ack, sorry. Didn't realize that wasn't mentioned in the question. Yes, popup form is `Details`.

Comment: Let's take a step back. The error msg title is **Write Conflict**, and this much is AFAIK always true. It happens when your Access frontend writes data, but notices that the record it wants to save has been changed inbetween. So the error must arise from some save operation, it cannot be only the opening of the Details form. You must take a really close look into what happens *before* the error msg pops up.

Comment: If another user actually has changed the record (or record page) you want to edit, the msg is simply telling the truth. But still, there must be a write / save in your instance to trigger it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to save, use `Cancel = True`. BeforeUpdate would not trigger if form is not dirty so don't bother with `If Me.Dirty`.

```
 ' Prompt to confirm the save operation.
 If MsgBox("Do you want to save?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Save Record") = vbNo Then
     Cancel = True
     Me.Undo
 End If
```

Comment: The problem lies from when the data DOES save. After saving (say changing a checkbox or something), then going to open another individual, the write error pops up. This does not occur when I do not save. Also, the save prompt is given when closing the window (there is no save button, but I imagine the process is the same).

Comment: I still cannot replicate issue. Code works perfect for me whether saving or not saving. There is no save prompt when closing form. I am able to open popup to another record. Error handlers actually interfere with debugging. Disable then set breakpoints and step debug. I suspect that record on subform is somehow placed into edit mode and this causes write conflict with same record on popup form. The subform SourceObject and popup are two different form objects?

Comment: The subform has a Source Object = to the subform, which depends on the `Table`. The `(Details) Form` Record Source is the `Table`. The save code works fine, there just appears to be something wonky with my set-up I think.

Comment: That doesn't really confirm that there are two different form objects in use for subform and popup. What is name of object in SourceObject property and what is name of popup form? Edit question to show example data and relationships.

Comment: I have solved the problem. To be honest, I changed some settings, then changed them back, and everything just fixed itself. Very strange! But I have accepted your answer as I did find it useful.